# Azure function: System.InvalidOperationException: Storage account connection string 'does not exist

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I have written an azure function, currently the azure function is acting as Webhook Consumer. The job of the function is to read Webhook events and save into azure storage.
I am using an HTTP trigger template to get the job done. I am able to receive the events from the Webhook, but when I try to write to azure storage it is giving me below error.

I tried the option mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152416/write-output-to-blob-in-azure-functions), but no luck still getting the same error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobs<AzureStorageAccountName>' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.
```

Below is my **function.json** file

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputblob",
      "path": "test/demo",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "<AzureStorageAccountName>"
    }    
  ]
}
```

***init*.py**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest,outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = 'some_name'
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = 'req_body_test'#req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
        name = 'name'#req_body.get('name')
    
    print(str(req.get_json()))

    outputblob.set(str(req.get_json()))
```

Comment: Do you have the `AzureWebJobsStorage` app setting defined? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage. If not, create it in the expected format and that should solve the issue.

Comment: Can you show your setting structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Please make sure you have already add the connection string to the local.settings.json on local or configuration settings on azure.

Please test below code and settings files:

**`__init__.py`**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest,outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    outputblob.set("this is a test.")
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "Test.",
            status_code=200
    )
```

**`function.json`**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "test/demo",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`local.settings.json`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

On azure:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I am not facing Storing acc connecting string error but getting below exception now: : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The requested operation is not allowed in the current state of the entity. 2021-03-03T08:27:43.963680879Z: [INFO] at –

Comment: @nilesh1212 Any limit on your storage account?

Comment: I am to store data into azure storage with by following your steps. The above error was due to my error. Thanks. Need one more help how do I store output in date/systime.json format on azure storage

Comment: @nilesh1212 Can you create a new question to describe your needs? :) I'm going to have dinner, please wait a moment.

Comment: Sure enjoy your dinner :)