# unable to encode outgoing TypedData: unsupported type "<class 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.generic.GenericBinding'>" for Python type "DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas, azure, file-io, azure-functions

i'm trying to upload the file that i have accessed to, via SAS key, and i have cleaned to azure Blob Storage. as you can see i have used BlobTrigger for this. I can't figure out how to deal with this Error or how i can convert this into a DataFrame (i have already tried to convert to Panda dataframe). Also i have read [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python) maybe i have missed a point.

The Error that i got:

> Failure Exception: TypeError: unable to encode outgoing TypedData: unsupported type "<class 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.generic.GenericBinding'>" for Python type "DataFrame"

basically i'm reading an Excel file and i want to Write the Excel file back to another Container.

Function.Json file:

```
{
 "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input/{name}.xlsx",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "output/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**init**.py file:

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[bytes]):
  def read_excel_files(_container, _filename):
      sas = generate_SAS(f"{_container}", f"{_filename}")
      blob_url = f'https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{_container}/{_filename}?{sas}'
      return pd.read_excel(blob_url)

  if myblob.name.__contains__("Book"):
      logging.info("Book was found")
      Buch = read_excel_files("_container", "_filename.xlsx")
      logging.info("Starting cleaning Process")
      ...
      logging.info("Cleaning is finished")        
      outputblob.set(Buch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as described in another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60152718/4575197) and the [linked Code](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/v2functions/queue-trigger-blob-in-out-binding/__init__.py#L27) i had to upload as string to Azure.
i post only part of my code that i changed.

```
outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> None:

 #everything is the same
 #Change the your variable to string before uploading
 outputblob.set(Buch.to_string())
```